# Disable clipping in CALayer

Tags: iphone, quartz-graphics, calayer

How do I disable clipping in a CALayer? I am overriding drawInContext, but I want to be able to draw lines that extend outside the bounds of the CALayer and I do not want to do a separate drawing pass on the parent layer to make this happen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't draw using Quartz outside of the bounds of a CALayer or UIView.  As Noah suggests, you'll need to expand the bounds of the layer by a set amount in order to draw this.

You can still do this without having to do some drawing in the parent layer, as long as your parent layer's `masksToBounds` property is set to NO.  That way, even if your sublayer extends out past the edge of the parent, it will still be drawn properly.

Comment: Do you know what kind of performance hit this would have? (if any). I have between 100 and 200 layers, and this would add another 100 to 200 layers...

Comment: @JJC - This approach wouldn't add any layers, just require an expansion of the bounds of existing ones.  It is slower to draw over larger areas, but hopefully that would be a one-time operation.  Larger layers do use more memory, but it sounds like you'd just want to extend things out a little bit.

Comment: I see, and then I would just have to change my drawing code to draw in the center of the layer and then draw the line appropriately. I think this is probably the best solution, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Well, `CALayer` has a `masksToBounds` property (which, set to `NO`, disables the default clipping to the layer's boundaries) but I don't think it affects the drawing of the layer itself—just the clipping of its sublayers. If you can't expand the frame of the layer itself for some reason, you'll need to set that property on the layer, add a bigger sublayer that has the dimensions you want to draw within, and move your drawing code to that sublayer.